# How do I slide a div in jquery galleria with elements inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, galleria

I am using galleria jquery plugin.

I have a div with class "carousel", This div will have many divs under it, which may also have divs beneath them. See Below:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url('some/bg/image.png');">
        <div class="info_item">
            <div class="ex">exclusive screening</div>
            <div class="movie_t"><a href="/events/view/2/title">Title</a></div>
            <div class="movie_w">Date: Location></div>
            <div class="av">AVAILABILITY: tickets</div>
        </div><!-- .info_item -->
    </div><!-- End of  div .img -->
</div> <!-- End of .carousel -->
```

Basically, right now when I run this code:

```
$(".carousel").galleria({
                width: 768,
                height: 209,
                thumbnails: false,
                autoplay: 4000,
                imageCrop: false,
                showCounter: false
        });
```

But this either does 2 things. Either the image will not show, and it will be "black/blank", or the image does show, but the divs inside it do not (The Text to be overlayed on the div .img).

Any ideas what im doing wrong? how can I achieve this easily. I basically need a slider, that I can customize the divs inside it fully, I would like to stay with galleria if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, Galleria only supports images and not div or other elements within the carousel, strictly images.
I needed to search 'jQuery content slider' not 'image slider'.

Hopes this helps someone with the same problem.

Galleria is only used for images, for divs and all other content, you need a content slider.